# Casting a List<MyClass> back from object returns a System.InvalidCastException C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, exception, deep-copy, generic-list

I have a `Dictionary<string,object>` where I save objects to parse to my plugin system, some of these objects need to be a copy not the original so I use this DeepClone method:

```
public static T DeepCloneJSON<T>(this T Obj)
        {
            var text = JsonSerializer.Serialize(Obj);
            return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(text);
        }
```

for example, if I do :

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string,object>(){
    {"someKey",new List<MyClass>(){new MyClass()}}
}
var copy = dict["someKey"].DeepCloneJSON();
var cast = (List<MyClass>)copy;
```

i get a System.InvalidCastException, but if i use a MemoryStream DeepCopy method i don't get this exception, like this one:

```
public static T DeepCloneMemoryStream<T>(this T obj)
        {
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                formatter.Serialize(ms, obj);
                ms.Position = 0;

                return (T)formatter.Deserialize(ms);
            }
        }
```

so, I would like to know why I get this exception using a System.text.json based DeepClone Method and if it is possible to do this with a System.text.json because in my tests it presents to be faster and use less memory than a MemoryStream based onde.

Comment: Because you are calling `DeepCloneJSON<object>` which in turn calls `JsonSerializer.Deserialize<object>` not `JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyClass>`. You are going to need reflection to call `DeepCloneJSON` with the correct type parameter. Although whether you should deep-clone via JSON at all is a different question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `DeepCloneMemoryStream` recreates the exact type via Reflection, even if `T` is object.

Your `DeepCloneJSON` roundtrip via JSON string loses type information, and so deserialization requires the exact type to be specified. In your case, you are only passing `object` as `T` and therefore you get back a `JsonElement` instead of a `List<MyClass>`.

The following will work if you change how you make your call:

```
var copy = DeepCloneJSON((List<MyClass>)dict["someKey"]);
```

Alternatively, change your implementation such that deserialization happens according to that actual type of `Obj` instead of the specified type `T` - this would have the analogous effect to your other implementation, where `T` is only used for casting.

```
public static T DeepCloneJSON<T>(T Obj)
{
    var text = JsonSerializer.Serialize(Obj);
    return (T)JsonSerializer.Deserialize(text, Obj.GetType());
}
```

**A completely different approach**

You can avoid the cast exception and the overhead of serializing and deserializing, and the possible issues with that (e.g. private members, non-serializable instances and such) by choosing among various open source NuGet packages that use techniques such as reflection emit or expression trees to avoid the serialization.

One example is [FastDeepCloner](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FastDeepCloner/) as suggested in the comments. There are several others that provide similar features.